# Determine unique builds

Tags: c#, reflection, deployment

In our project, there are cases when code changes are made on the fly and deployed over the devices. This is made by multiple developers.

We have a requirement where we need to generate a unique hashcode for a specific set of code when build is created. So for eg initially the hash code is "abcd".

I changed code in a CS file Employee.cs and updated a method. Once I compile the hash code should change to something else e.g "defg".

If I revert my changes, it should revert to "abcd".

Is this possible to do? I am using C#.

Comment: That's essentially how git works internally, so I guess you could use the hash of the root directory that git stores in the .git folder somehow.

Comment: There is no git. However I got something similar to my requirements in this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501631/Compare-Two-DLL-Files-Programmatically-Using-Hash

Comment: Git compares files. I need to put a hash in a log file to identify if something has changed between the version deployed now and the old deployment version.

Comment: Ah, I made the assumption you had automated deployment from git commits. That solution you found seems like a good start. Be mindful of framework updates though, as they might change the compilation between equal codebases.

Comment: Even this does not solve my purpose. When I change and revert the code, it gives a different hash. :( :(